# PHP Search form in SQL database/table

Tags: php, sql, forms, search

I have a table with many columns

```
( A , B , C , D , E)
```

I have search form and it's works

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT * 
    FROM Database 
    WHERE Name LIKE '%{$search}%'
");
```

On B column I have Names, on A column I have numbers.

I want to search a name from column B and to display it only if `A = 0`.

Comment: select * from Database where Name like '%{$search}% AND number =0 use this query

Comment: so `"...where Name like '%{$search}%' and A = 0"`? Using `like %%` is really slow for searching, consider using full text search instead: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Add `AND number = 0` in where. Also don't use variables directly in the query, you're killing the advantage of prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Database 
WHERE Name LIKE '%{$search}%' 
   AND A = 0
```

Comment: ("SELECT * 
FROM zentraldatenbank 
WHERE Interne_Name LIKE '%{$search}%' 
AND SKU = 0");

doesn't work..

Comment: You should give more information then. For information you gave this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query would be the following, using '?' on LIKE to use the prepared statement logic, it is replaced on the next line for the variable $search.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT * 
    FROM Database 
    WHERE B LIKE '%?%' AND A=0
");
$sth->execute(array($search));
```